# How can I combine three cells (e.g. '23','7','10') to form an 'hour/day/month' cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

My idea is to have this 'date format' cell in order to graph prices that corresponds to each hour and have a around 10.000 rows of information for every year. This is what it looks like when I download these prices for any year

[image: prices for any year]

As you can see, there will be between 720-744 different prices through a month and I'd like to see the variation in time (last 6 years for example) of these prices, for example

[image: Example]

I want to do this because of what I've read for these charts, but if you have a better/efficient approach I would be truly appreciated to hear it.

Comment: `hour/day/month` without a year component have no sense. When you add a year component the task became trivial.

Comment: In Column `C` write Hours like `20:00` and apply `24 Hrs format like [h]:mm` then in `D2` you may write this , `=TEXT(C2,"HH, ")&TEXT(B2,"DDd, ")&TEXT(A2,"MMM") , you get `20, Wed, Jan`

Comment: Your volume of data doesn't exceed Excel's limits, but that will get slow.  I think the chart data limit is 32,000 data points (at least as of a few years ago).  But that much data in an Excel chart will be a mess.  You might want to explore other tools designed to handle this quantity of data.  Also, consider ways to reduce data points for charting (aggregate, sample, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The functions [DATEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) and [TIMEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645) converts a date or time that is stored as text to a serial number that Excel recognizes as a date or time. You could simply add the two to get the needed DateTime value.

```
=DATEVALUE(B3&"/"&A3&"/2018")+TIMEVALUE(C3&":00:00")
```

You might need to generate the correct string to match you locale (ie. using YMD format):

```
=DATEVALUE("2018."&A3&"."&B3)+TIMEVALUE(C3&":00:00")
```

Set the custom format `hh/dd/mm` on the cells containig the results.